# i have code that create 20 button horizontally ,how to make the buttons Vertically

Tags: c#

[image]

this is the code that create the buttons

```
      public System.Windows.Forms.Button creatbtn()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
        btn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Top = c * 28;
        btn.Left = 150;
        btn.Text = "button" + this.c.ToString();
        c = c + 1;


        }
        return btn;
    }
```

Comment: Calculate `Left` dynamically instead of `Top` to lign the buttons horizontally -currently the **are** aligned vertically

Comment: `btn.Top =  28; btn.Left = 150 + c * 80;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Dmitry Bychenko sait
Just do the same you did for top but do it for left

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Button creatbtn()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        btn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Controls.Add(btn);

        //btn.Top = c * 28
        btn.Top = 28;

        //btn.Left = 150
        btn.Left = 150 + (c * (btn.Width + 5));

        btn.Text = "button" + this.c.ToString();
        c++;
    }
    return btn;
}
```